# How do I get the value of id="text1" to be added at the end of the URL?

Tags: javascript

I am more the hardware guy and my programming skills really suck. I am trying to create things mostly by trial and error and the help of google. I am helping out some GFX-/Ad-Designers, who basically create stuff, place it on a website and have to run those websites thru severals browsers. I am trying to make this less manually handed.

This is run in a HTA. As I said, I am not a programming guy and this was something I could easly work with =/ probably some other language could do this by ease...but as said...

**tl;dr**

**How do I get the value of id="text1" to be added at the end of the URL**

shell.run("Firefox https://www.example.com=(text1.value)"); doesnt work.

I does work if I manually change the URL, but than I would not have a handy input-field and changing the URLs by hand...I guess the ad-creating ppl will mess up things.

So, thats what I have done so far...but I can't fix it.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sub-Site Automation</title>
  <hta:application applicationname="Run test on browsers" scroll="yes" singleinstance="yes">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function openURL()
  {
      var input = document.getElementById("text1");
/*     console.log(input); // Log
*/
      var inputValue = input.value;
/*     console.log(inputValue); // Log2
*/
      
      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
          shell.run("Firefox https://www.example.com=(text1.value)");
          shell.run("Chrome https://www.example.com=(text1.value)");
 shell.run("file:///C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe https://www.example.com=(text1.value)");
      
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="text1" Name="text1" value="Place ID of subwebsite here"><br>
<input type="submit" Value="Open in all Webbrowsers" onclick="openURL()">

</body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Comment: The answer is in your code itself.

Comment: enlighten me pls. I tried fixing it, but failed. Probably its just how the value is placed with "(text1.value)" or "("text1.value")"? I tried all versions which came to my mind...

Comment: Added an answer. Please check. @Captain.Obvious

Comment: Thank you @sanketd617 for fixing my stuff! Really appreciated!

Comment: Thank you @K3v1n 0X90 for fixing my stuff! Really appreciated!

Comment: Small step for you guys, but worlds for me =)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the answer is in your code itself.

See the lines:

```
// This line gets the element you want
var input = document.getElementById("text1");

// This line gets it's value. You need this value
var inputValue = input.value;
```

The variable `inputValue` is what you need to replace there instead of using `text1.value`.

So your function would be as follows:

```
function openURL() { 
    var input = document.getElementById("text1"); 
    var inputValue = input.value; 
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.run("Firefox https://www.example.com=("+inputValue+")"); 
    shell.run("Chrome https://www.example.com=("+inputValue+")");    
    shell.run("file:///C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe https://www.example.com=("+inputValue+")");
}
```

Comment: You corrected my stuff! I had to take away the brackets, ("+inputValue+") looks now like "+inputValue+" and works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the problem ist that you have no reference to the elements with id text1 so you can not access its value. A second problem is that you try to access a variable inside of a string literal which could be solved in es5 with string concatenation or in newer ecmascript versions with template literals.

Depending on the input value you should also use encodeURIComponent so that the resulting URL is valid.
One version that would work is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sub-Site Automation</title>
  <hta:application applicationname="Run test on browsers" scroll="yes" singleinstance="yes">      
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="text1" Name="text1" value="Place ID of subwebsite here"><br>
<input type="submit" Value="Open in all Webbrowsers" onclick="openURL()">

<script type="text/javascript">
  function openURL()
  {
      var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");                    
      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      shell.run("Firefox https://www.example.com=" + text1.value);
      shell.run("Chrome https://www.example.com=" + text1.value);
      shell.run("file:///C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe https://www.example.com=" + text1.value);          
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you fixed it! I knew it had something to do with the value and how it is called up. Thank you!